# Why does my C code print out different values when referring to the same variable?

Tags: c, debugging, scope, undefined-behavior

Here's goes my first attempt at a question on stackoverflow -

I have the following implemented in C:

When running my program, I have realized that the value of hashstring printed out differs in the two following functions:

```
void foo() {
    ...
    Obj *obj = Obj(args);
    char *hashstring = getHash(obj);
    printf("My value of hashstring: %s\n", hashstring);
    ...
}

char* getHash(Obj *obj) {
    ...
    int hashint = getHashInt(args);
    // I am trying to do a conversion from int to string here
    char hashstring[12]; 
    sprintf(hashstring, "%d", hashint);
    printf("My value of hashstring: %s\n", &hashstring);
    return &hashstring;
}
```

*Here's what gets printed out:* 
My value of hashstring: 1001 // printing in getHash: this is the expected 
My value of hashstring: 0 
My value of hashstring: 2002 // printing in getHash: this is the expected 
My value of hashstring: 0 
My value of hashstring: 3003 // printing in getHash: this is the expected 
My value of hashstring: 0

I have tried debugging by printing the pointer of hashstring instead, in foo(). It seems like in every single call, I am getting the same address for hashstring.

*Here's what gets printed out:* 
0x7ffee1992f54 
0x7ffee1992f54 
0x7ffee1992f54

I guessed that this probably meant that I am somehow referencing the same hashstring variable in getHash(), which is strange since I am creating a new variable each time.  I have also tried other variants like snprintf(hashstring, 12, "%d", hashint) in getHash(), or creating a char *pointerToHash and passing in *pointerToHash to sprintf.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post [mcve] please. Indentation helps too.

Comment: First, it's confusing to have local variables with the same name in two different functions.  The array `hashstring` in `getHash` is local, and its lifetime ends when `getHash` returns.  So returning its address results in a pointer that `main` cannot use.  That memory, as you see, may be overwritten by something else at any time.  A good compiler should give you warnings about this.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with the emphasis on complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
char* getHash(Obj *obj) {
...
int hashint = getHashInt(args);
// I am trying to do a conversion from int to string here
char hashstring[12]; 
sprintf(hashstring, "%d", hashint);
printf("My value of hashstring: %s\n", &hashstring);
return &hashstring;
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because it returns a pointer to the local array

```
 char hashstring[12];
```

that will not be alive after exiting the function.

Moreover the return type of the function `char *` and the type of the returned expression `char ( * )[12]` are different and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

To avoid the problem you should allocate the array dynamically like for example

```
char *hashstring = calloc( 12, sizeof( char ) );
```

and in the return statement write

```
return hashstring;
```

Then in the caller you should free the allocated memory when the allocated array will not be needed any more.